# Setting EditText left or right drawable with animation

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-animation

I want to add simple fade animation over EditText on setting the left or right drawable.

Is there any simple workaround for this?

```
 edtText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,
            0, drawableResId, 0)
```

Comment: I added fade animation over EditText instead drawable only

Answer (score 1):

If your drawable is animated like an [AnimationDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable) you could do:

```
AnimationDrawable d = (AnimationDrawable) getResources()
    .getDrawable(R.drawable.whatever_drawable);
edtText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, d, null);
d.start();
```

`d.start` should start the animation and at some point you should call `d.stop()` to stop it.